# Can't remove wires from a circuit breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

I'm trying to remove a breaker in the electric panel.  It's an ITE GFCI in a Gould panel, now owned by Siemens.  It can be as old as about 38 years.  The load line releases easily with a set screw.  Then...

There are **3 wires** connected to the breaker **through the same port**, with no visible means of releasing them --- **no set screw and no hole in which to insert a tool to push on a spring-type release**  The 3 wires are:

1. the load neutral (white)
2. the panel neutral (white with a black spiral stripe)
3. a 2 or 3" wire (dark grey) which loops around and enters another port in the breaker with a set screw that is blocked from use by a cover over the screw-head slot.

Since I have to remove the load neutral to replace the breaker:

- How do I release the load neutral or all 3 wires at once?
- Do I have to cut the load neutral at the breaker and re-strip the end of the wire?
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

Comment: What country are you in? On the GE GFCI breakers I have, the (white) neutral from the house wiring is secured with a set screw just like the (black) hot. Then there is a (white) neutral *from* the breaker (to the neutral bus bar) which is permanently bonded to the breaker. One loosens its attachment screw on the neutral bar.

Comment: Can you post close-ups of the situation?

Comment: The wires are exactly as described.  **3 wires**, including the load neutral, are attached to the breaker **through a single port**, with NO set screw or other apparent releasing mechanism. I will try to get a picture tomorrow. @JimStewart

Comment: What is the ampere rating of this breaker? Is it a single pole or double pole?

Comment: The breaker is 15 amps, single pole.  As printed on the breaker: "Class A  1 Pole  Unit Issue A-345" and "Cat. No. OFI-BO15".   (In the catalog designation, I'm reading from my own written notes.  Without rechecking the breaker, there is confusion between zeros and the letter "O", and between the number 1 and the letter "I".)

Comment: Also printed on the breaker are the brand names "ITE" and "Gould".  And, yes, the house is located in south Florida, which I believe is still in the USA.  <br/> @ThreePhaseEel,

Comment: some breakers have pre attached pig tails if this is the case follow the wire to the connection and remove it there. I don't remember other than the neutral ever being fixed.

Comment: Exactly @EdBeal -- the GFCI-to-bus neutral is already pigtailed, why not others on an early breaker?  I wrote a comment suggesting OP follow the wires and look for any wire-nuts... but the comment did not post for some reason.

Comment: I was having trouble earlier reading a post that mentioned other comments that were not there must have been a glitch in the system although I have not had many problems with the exchange so far.

Comment: @Harper -- The load neutral does, indeed, connect with what seems to be a split wire under a wire nut.  I presume that is to share a neutral path to the neutral bar.  My inability to release this load neutral (white) wire is what is preventing me from changing the breaker.

Comment: Are you saying that the wire nut won't unscrew? Early model Scotchloks were this way. Sometimes one had to crush the metal capsule with pliers to unscrew them.

Comment: I suppose I could use some tool to unblock that set screw, but I don't need to mess with that one to change the breaker.  The set screw that releases the load line is fine.  I can remove that wire.  And the panel neutral is no problem, because I can remove it from the neutral bus.  I'll be using the pigtail on the new breaker for the panel neutral.

Comment: Now that you have +10 rep, you may be able to post directly using the "Edit question" and the "image" button.  Does not work on iOS.  You need to shrink down pictures larger than 2MB, but if you can upload it anywhere and post the link, mods can do that.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I am eager to do what I can to help you help me.  However, generallyI do not trust websites.  It took **A LOT** for me to join Stack Exchange!  Still, with great trepidation, I used the image button in a question edit.  I dragged the first photo into Imgur, which seemed to accept the photo; but it doesn't appear with my original question.  I hate it when I've given a site a link to myself and gotten nothing in return.  It creates distrust in me.  My pics will make it easiest for you to help me, but without a direct link to this site, it may not be possible.  I'm still open.

Comment: @jimmyd -- imgur does not require any accounts or identifying information to use, if that's where your trust issues lie.

Comment: As to using the image insert function itself -- just hit edit on your question here, and the button that looks like a picture, then drag your image into the dialog that appears, and hit the add picture button.

Comment: That's what I did. So where did my picture go?

Comment: It might have been too large -- did you get a red error message in the dialog when you tried?

Comment: Hi @jimmyd! Sorry that you're having problems with the site. Full instructions for adding an image to the post are at https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/524/22.

Comment: Today, I manged to use the icon in the question edit to present you with pictures.  The answer to this dilemma will now be provided under "Answer Your Question"

Comment: Kudos to @Harper for thinking outside the box.  My first thought when I saw those 3 wires was that they were like the single permanent pigtail attached to the new breaker I had bought to replace the old one.

Comment: I made a big mistake in the first line of my answer.  I typed "...cut the load line at the wire" instead of "cut the load line at the BREAKER".  Because of this, someone being helpful put in a link to one of my photos of the "far" end of the load neutral (which is peripheral to the primary question) instead of one of my pictures of all the wires connected to the breaker (which IS the primary issue).  Would someone please correct this?  I don't know how to. @Harper,@JimStewart

Comment: Better yet, if someone could place my picture(s) under the numbered paragraphs which refer to them, the presentation of the answer would be in the best form.  I don't know how to move them. I realized after all the pictures were entered that I should have constructed the answer in that order.  Thanks to all for all the input and assistance.@harper,@JimStewart  (I have corrected my wording in the answer.

Comment: I figured out how to move the pictures.  The long answer to the question is easier to read now, with the relevant photo(s) closer to each part of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The dilemma: **do I cut the load neutral at the breaker, or is there a way to remove it from the breaker?**

Remember: the load line is purple; the load neutral is white; the panel neutral is white with a black stripe; the short loop from one side of the breaker to the other is dark grey (may look black in the photos).

1. The first 3 photos (below) show different angles of all 4 wires and where they connect to this ITE GFCI breaker. Notice: There are 3 ports where the wires connect. **3 wires** (the white, the striped and one end of the grey loop) **enter a single port**. The purple and the other end of the grey loop have their own port for connection.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2OWE.jpg  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LGLP.jpg  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oVE0.jpg

2. The second photo (above) also shows the top of two set-screws. (Look at the breaker in the middle of the three shown.) The one on the right releases the line load (purple) wire, and looks normal. The one on the left releases the stand-alone end of the grey wire loop; but you can't see any groove for a screwdriver or other tool because ITE put a cover/block over the head of the screw. Clearly, they don't want someone removing that screw, especially accidentally.
3. The third photo (above): Look at the broad side of the breaker. Notice 4 small shallow holes with something somewhat bright inside each one. These bright objects are either rivets or another type of fastener that either hold the breaker case together or hold internal parts to the breaker case.

   I mention this because when I found no set-screw(s) to release the 3 wires in the same port, I looked for a hole in which to insert a tool to push on some kind of spring release of the wires. As you can see, there is no such hole, and this is the broad side of the breaker closest to those 3 wires. You can also see fairly well, from all of the first 3 photos, that there is no such hole on the thin side of the breaker to which all the wires attach. There are also no such holes on the opposite broad side of the breaker (no photo).
4. The fourth photo (below) shows the same broad side of the breaker as above. Notice:

   - You can see all 4 wires just above the top of the image of the breaker.
   - You can see two of the four rivets/fasteners.
   - You can see 3 embossed labels. I couldn't get a half-decent photo of these labels, but...

     - The one just under the 3 wires in the same port identifies those wires. It says, one under another: "Load Lug", "Plain Wire - Load Neut.", "Stripe Wire - Neut. Bus"
     - The one in the center of the breaker includes "Use only UL approved..." and "ITE Imperial Corp...Pennsylvania".
     - The one in the upper left corner says "STRIP GAGE" and has an embossed line of the length to strip the wires.
   - There are a few identifying codes stamped in white, not all still entirely legible, even in person.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWLui.jpg

5. In the fifth photo (below):

   - You can see directly into the 2 set-screw ports, and see that you can see the screwdriver slot at the top of the set-screw on the right, but not the one on the left, which is covered/blocked. (There's no need to access the one on the left in order to replace the breaker.)
   - The L-shaped yellowish-brownish area below the set-screws is the residue from the glued-on breaker label, which came off during my handling of the breaker, probably when I pulled off the tape that I used to hold the switch in the off position while working. The label included:

     i) "Class A 1 Pole Unit Issue A-345"

     ii) "Current Interrupting Rating"

     iii) "Gould Corp. Circuit Protection Division Philadelphia, Penn. USA"

     iv) "I-T-E Circuit Breaker & Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter"

     v) "CAT. NO. OFI-B015" (The letter "O" may actually the number zero and the letter "I" may actually be the number "1" in "OFI". The number
     "0" may actually be the letter "O" in "B015". I think I got it right, but my own handwriting is unclear and I don't have the label anymore to double-check it.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRyjj.jpg

6. In the sixth photo (below), our breaker is the highest one. Notice:

   - You can see all 4 wires.
   - If you follow the white load neutral, you can see that it connects with either two other wires or a split wire, which is/are grey, under a yellow wire nut.  
     (Note: These wires at the wire nut are irrelevant to changing the breaker, except in one case:  If the load neutral has to be cut from the breaker and it ends up **too short** to reach the new breaker when that breaker is properly attached to the panel, then you have to **replace** the load neutral (white) wire with a longer wire (of the same/correct gauge), which means undoing the wire nut to remove the "far" end of the old load neutral wire and replace it with the "far" end of the new load neutral wire.)
   - It's not all in the picture, but if you carefully follow the striped panel neutral, you can see that it heads downward, then curves back upward and proceeds above the breaker, along the right edge of the line of the breakers. (It's hard to see the highest part.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah9J6.jpg

7)  In the seventh photo (below), the breaker is not installed into the panel. Notice:

- You can see the striped panel neutral where it went above the breaker and finally turns and connects to the neutral bar.
- You can see the yellow wire nut containing the "far" end of the load neutral (white) and the two grey wires. (It's hard to see both grey wires.)
- In the lower left corner of the image, you can see the empty slot from which the breaker was removed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOQP4.jpg

8) The eighth photo (below) shows the utility side of the breaker.  Notice:

- You can see the white "TEST" button and the ON/OFF switch of this GFCI breaker.
- You can see the yellowish L-shaped area where the glued-on label used to be.
- You can see part of the "back" broad side and two of the four 'rivet-holes' there.  There are no holes to insert a tool to press a spring to release those 3 wires in the single port.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYi8v.jpg

I included all the details I could about this breaker for those who really want to "see" what I've been looking at and who may want to research further.  Especially, because the issue was **finding a way to remove the load neutral from the breaker**, I wanted to show you every square inch of the breaker so you could look for yourself.

It turns out that one of my relatives has a friend who has been a master electrician for over 40 years, has lived in this area for his whole life, has not only worked for many years for the county where this house is located, but done so as an electrician and as an electrical inspector.  He agreed to come here to give me some honest input about some significant electrical work we have been considering doing. ("Honest", because he is a good friend of my relative and because he will not be doing the work.)

I also informed him that I need help with the breaker.  I sent him a photo at his request because he also couldn't picture it from my description.

Before he arrived, I saw a former neighbor and good acquaintance who also happens to be a master electrician who I trust, also with over 40 years' experience.  I described the breaker to him, and he was also puzzled by my description.

When the electrician arrived, we went right to the breaker.  He turned it every which way to look it over, then looked where each wire led.  After assessing everything, he told me he had never seen a breaker like this, not the short wire loop and not the 3 wires in a single port.  Then, **he confirmed what seemed obvious to me as the answer to my question, but what I did not want to act on without such confirmation:**

**There is no way to release those 3 wires.  The load line has to be cut at the breaker.** (Fortunately, after cutting it, it was still long enough to reach the new breaker.)

The design of this breaker may be a dinosaur that went extinct long ago.